# Extendable Train Swapping Problem

Tags: code-golf, sorting, graph-theory, path-finding, permutations

## Extended Train Swapping Problem

#### Part 1: Normal Train Swapping Problem

In the 1996 CCC (Canadian Computing Competition), the first Stage 2 problem was a Train Swapping Problem. You can visit the link [here](http://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/computing/1996/stage2/21a-prob.html). Essentially, you have a bunch of numbered trains, and you want to find out how many train swaps you need to get them in order, and each train swap operation allows you to swap two adjacent trains. Since train carriages can run either way, nobody cares about the fact that the train carriages face the other way when swapped. This is pretty easy; all you need to do is:

> Find the number of steps to bubble-sort it; it's the most efficient sorting algorithm when you can only make adjacent element swaps

So, I made a harder one.

#### Part 2: How this challenge works

Essentially, you can now swap more than just adjacent trains. With a longer rotating platform, you can swap the position of multiple trains. For example, with a rotating platform of length 4, you can swap both the inner and outer pairs at the same time, so `1 2 3 4` becomes `4 3 2 1`. Here are some examples for different rotating platform sizes:

```
Length 2:
1 2 3 4 5
  ---
1 3 2 4 5

Length 3:
1 2 3 4 5
  -----
1 4 3 2 5

Length 4:
1 2 3 4 5
-------
4 3 2 1 5
```

Essentially, you're just inverting a sublist of the entire train. To clarify, in each move, you can only swap *exactly* `N` trains.

#### Part 3: Specifications

### Input

Your input must take in two things: the length of the rotating platform, and the order of the train carriages. You may also require the number of train carriages if you wish. The order of the train carriages is given by an ordered list of numbers (each number representing a train carriage), so you can read the input as space-separated integers, newline-separated integers, an array, etc.

### Output

You must output the optimal (minimum) number of swaps needed to get the carriages all into the order `1 2 3 ... N`. If there is no solution, output `-1`, `No solution`, or some other consistent message. You may not output to stderr.

### Scoring

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so scoring is in bytes. The solution with the lowest number of bytes as of September 1st, 2016 will be the accepted one.

### Examples

**Problem 1**
**Input**

```
4
2
1 3 2 4
```

**Output**

```
1
```

**Explanation**
This is pretty trivial; with a rotating platform of length 2, it's the same as the normal train swapping problem. Swap the `2` and the `3`.

**Problem 2**
**Input**

```
4
3
1 3 2 4
```

**Output**

```
No solution (or an equivalent consistent message).
```

**Problem 3**
**Input**

```
9
3
1 4 5 6 3 8 7 2 9
```

**Output**

```
4
```

**Explanation**

```
1 4 5 6 3 8 7 2 9
          -----
1 4 5 6 3 2 7 8 9
      -----
1 4 5 2 3 6 7 8 9
    -----
1 4 3 2 5 6 7 8 9
  -----
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

[Standard loopholes apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

Good luck!

**EDIT 1**: Made the input format more flexible. Thanks to @Mego!
**EDIT 2**: Clarified that a rotating platform of length 4 swaps both the inner *and* outer pairs. Thanks to @TimmyD!
**EDIT 3**: Clarified that you must make permutations of length `N` exactly, not at most. Thanks to @Zgarb!

Comment: Having such a strict input format is not a good idea. Any input format, so long as only the list of train carriages (and optionally the length of this list) and the length of the platform is transmitted, should be acceptable.

Comment: @Mego Okay, I will make the change.

Comment: @TimmyD Yes. I will clarify this in the challenge.

Comment: Does a length-**N** platform flip exactly **N** trains, or at most **N** trains?

Comment: @Zgarb Oh. I forgot to consider that. It's exactly **N** trains. I will clarify this in the challenge.

Comment: A question can only have 5 tags. I removed [tag:array-manipulation] because it's so generic as to be virtually useless, and I think the question is better served by the more specific tags I added.

Comment: I swear a variant of this was a GCJ problem once. But it had arbirtarily sized platforms, I think.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting.

Comment: Is terminating and printing nothing acceptable for the "no solution" case ?

Comment: @TonHospel Sorry for the late reply, yes it is acceptable, as long as there is no sort of error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Perl, 120 bytes

Includes +6 for `-Xapi` (`-` and space are counted too because both the `-i` and the `$'` in the code make it impossible to combine the options with `-e`)

Run with the input on STDIN and the platform length after the `-i` option, e.g.

```
perl -Xapi3 trains.pl <<< "1 4 5 6 3 8 7 2 9"
```

Prints `-2` if there is no solution

`trains.pl`:

```
1until$_=$n++*$z{pack"W*",@F}||-!grep!$z{$_}++&&/.{$^I}(??{!\$z{$`.reverse($&).$'}})$/s,keys%z,pack"W*",1..@F;$_--
```

if `N <= 9` then you can gain 5 more bytes:

```
1until$_=$n++*$z{join"",@F}||-!grep!$z{$_}++&&/.{$^I}(??{!\$z{$`.reverse($&).$'}})$/,keys%z,join"",1..@F;$_--
```

Comment: Good job; as far as I've tested, this works! +1 & accept